# UIImage bigger than constraints dimensions

Tags: swift, constraints

[image]

My constraints :

width = 100
height = 100

I'm using SDWebImage, the images look nice at first and then they grow bigger.

I am not sure how to use hugging and compression auto layout for sizing priorities.

Comment: Is that the `UIImageView` that is bigger, or the rendering of the `UIImage` in it? For instance, what's the value of `theImageView.clipsToBound` and `theImageView.contentMode`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set

```
self.imageView.clipsToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell = taBleView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TableViewCell

    cell.imageview.clipsTobounds = true
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.